# What does "peer sent transaction already received" mean?

Tags: mining-pools, p2pool

This is  my output from p2pool.

```
2013-07-10 16:06:29.543000 P2Pool: 17383 shares in chain (17388 verified/17388 total) Peers: 11 (5 incoming)
2013-07-10 16:06:29.544000  Local: 0H/s in last 0.0 seconds Local dead on arrival: ??? Expected time to share: ???
2013-07-10 16:06:29.544000  Shares: 0 (0 orphan, 0 dead) Stale rate: ??? Efficiency: ??? Current payout: 0.0000 BTC
2013-07-10 16:06:29.544000  Pool: 1074GH/s Stale rate: 17.1% Expected time to block: 23.7 hours
```

**Problem** - Why are there '???'s replacing all the values?

**Question 1** - What does the 'Peers: 11 (5 incoming)' mean

**Question 2** - What does the following line mean? It shows up a lot with different strings of numbers and letters:

```
2013-07-10 16:10:01.362000 Peer sent entire transaction 59900f72264267f0fbff2041ea50d9b72ba44448aa2244429e855f5372ba2bca that was already received
```

*Thank you for your time.*

Answer (score 1):

The "???"s mean that P2Pool has no estimate because nobody is mining on this node. "Peer sent entire transaction ..." is printed when a little bandwidth is wasted because peers are forwarding transactions needlessly.